# What is this Network Address from a driver?

Tags: networking

What is this network address, and what should I write here? Where should I find this address?

[image]

I think this is a MAC address.
I know that this address correct need then when my net cable plug other computer.

Comment: For what need you have to add an address there?

Comment: If you use DHCP, that should always be left as Not Present. tbh, if you don't know what anything is in that panel, leave it well alone. If you mess it up, you won't be able to get back here to ask the next question ;)

Comment: i want know from where bring this address because maybe need write

Answer (score 3):

Take a [look](http://alliedtelesis.com/manuals/2900IGa/SettingAdvancedProperties.html):

> **The Network Address is a user-defined address that is used to replace
>   the MAC address that was originally assigned to the adapter**. In some
>   operating systems, this property is called Locally Administered
>   Address. The network address consists of a 12-digit hexadecimal
>   number.
>
> To change the Network Address property, do the following:
>
> 1. For Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP systems, access the System Properties Dialog Box. See Modifying Configuration Properties.
>
> For Windows 2008 R2, Windows 7, and Windows Vista systems, access the
>   Device Manger for your operating system:
>
> ■ To access the Device Manager window in Windows 2008 R2 or Windows 7,
>   see Selecting the Device Manager in Windows 2008 R2 and Windows 7.
>
> ■ To access the Windows Vista Device Manager, see Selecting the Device
>   Manager in Windows Vista.
>
> 2. Click the Advanced tab.
>
> The Advanced tab is shown in Figure 21.
>
> 3. From the Property list on the Advanced tab, select Network Address.
> 4. In the Value list on the Advanced tab, enter the Locally Administered Address. Here are some guidelines:
>
> ■ The range is 0000 0000 0001 to FFFF FFFF FFFD.
>
> ■ Do not use a multicast address (least significant bit of the high
>   byte = 1).
>
> ■ Do not use all 0's or all F's.
>
> 5. Click OK.
> 6. If prompted to restart your computer, click Yes.
>
> Although it is not necessary to reboot the system for new adapter
>   properties to take effect, rebooting is recommended to reinitialize
>   all registers.
>
> 7. Verify that the port LED operates as described in LEDs.

Comment: aaa , yeah , such i knew , but this needed because that when i have my PC net plugged and that unplug and plug other computer my net cable here don't working net and need this mac adress write

Comment: when in computer isn't net  , ipconfig /all anyway show me physical address?